# Declare variables outside of Erlang functions

Tags: erlang

I'm currently reading through [learn you some Erlang](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/content) and I've implemented the following example:

```
get_weather(City) ->
    Weather = [{toronto, rain}, 
               {montreal, storms}, 
               {london, fog}, 
               {paris, sun}, 
               {boston, fog}, 
               {vancouver, snow}],
    [LocationWeather || {Location, LocationWeather} <- Weather, Location =:= City].
```

This example works fine, but if I want to declare the variable `Weather` outside of the function, I get the error:

```
solve.erl:5: syntax error before: Weather
solve.erl:2: function get_weather/1 undefined
```

Is there a way to declare variables outside of function scopes? Can I do this via header files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: no. Variables can be defined only within functions.

Another way to implement your function is to use pattern matching in function heads:

```
get_weather(toronto) -> rain;
get_weather(montreal) -> storms;
get_weather(london) -> fog;
get_weather(paris) -> sun;
get_weather(boston) -> fog;
get_weather(vancouver) -> snow.
```

With this approach, you don't need variables at all. You also get the result as a single atom, which I think is a better design than returning a single atom in a list.

Comment: How about within header files, we can declare `records` and export them, but not other types like `lists`?

Comment: @Suddi: Records are not values or even types. They are syntactic sugar around tuples. It is more like `-define` than anything else.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to define a function that returns the data list:

```
weather_data() -> [{toronto, rain}, 
                   {montreal, storms}, 
                   {london, fog}, 
                   {paris, sun}, 
                   {boston, fog},
                   {vancouver, snow}].
get_weather() ->
    [LocationWeather || {Location, LocationWeather} <- weather_data(), Location =:= City].
```